# Will throwing an ender pearl while holding a lead tied to a mob make the mob teleport with you?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know that riders get dismounted from horses, but what happens to mobs that you are tied to with a lead?

I cannot test it myself any time soon, and I am very curious. If the mob gets left behind, does the lead drop as an item where you were before the teleport, or does it remain in your hand?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Okay, I was actually able to test it in version 1.16.4:

Mob does NOT teleport with you.

Also:

1. If you teleport within lead's range, mob stays attached.
2. If you teleport outside lead's range, lead breaks and drops where you teleported from.